# LibGdx Issue of coordinates

Tags: libgdx

I have issue in my LibGdx program. I gave 800 height and 480 width to my camera. I am drawing target under  coordinates  :

```
randomTargetX = new Random().nextInt((350 - 100) + 1) + 100;
randomTargetY = new Random().nextInt((600 - 300) + 1) + 300;
```

But after clicking on target my cannonball don't overlap target rectangle.

I am doing this in Touch:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

            touchX = Gdx.input.getX();
            touchY = Gdx.input.getY();
            camera.unproject(touch.set(touchX, touchY, 0));

            if (touch.y>200) {
                isTouched = true;
                rectangleCannonBall.x = (width / 2) - 50 / 2;
                rectangleCannonBall.y = 0;

                double angle = 180.0 / Math.PI * Math.atan2(rectangleCannonBall.x - touch.x, touch.y - rectangleCannonBall.y);
                spriteCannon.setRotation((float) angle);
            }
        }
```

Doesn't work.

It's a cannonball game:

First i am setting camera.

Randomly showing targets inside range of coordinates.

On touch unprojecting camera with Vector3 new position.

On touch calculating target position with cannon position and getting angle to rotate cannon.

After rotating cannon I fire ball towards target.

Now when I do Rectanglar1.overlaps(rec2) , it doesn't work because of both rectangles have different points but by visible both overlaps each other.

When I check coordinates of Rectangle of Target and Touch its different.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
camera.unproject(touch.set(touchX, touchY, 0));
```

Doesn't do anything. 
Try with:

```
touch = camera.unproject(touch.set(touchX, touchY, 0));
```